# selenium is not support new chrome version

Tags: chromecast

I want to download selenium for chrome, but chrome's 115th version does not have selenium, can you help me?

#Latest ChromeDriver Binaries
Starting with M115 the latest Chrome + ChromeDriver releases per release channel (Stable, Beta, Dev, Canary) are available at the Chrome for Testing availability dashboard. For automated version downloading one can use the convenient JSON endpoints.

The older releases can be found at the Downloads page.
#this text get from chromedriver